# Deploying Azure ResourceGroup by template returns "not found"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

I have an Azure template and am attempting to deploy two extra resource groups.

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
  "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
  "location": "eastus",
  "name": "[variables('galleryResourceGroupName')]",
  "properties": {}
},
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
  "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "name": "[variables('tempResourceGroupName')]",
  "properties": {}
},
```

When I run this template, the result for these two resources is:

{
    "message": **"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI** 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/59b4b...9074/resourcegroups/rgMain/providers/Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups/rgTemp?api-version=2019-08-01'."
}

**NotFound**

The docs say you can deploy a resourceGroup:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.resources/2019-08-01/resourcegroups

But it is not working...
Any ideas why ?

Comment: How are you deploying this template?

Comment: You need to use the complete template, not a part of it. See [template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-create-first-template?tabs=azure-cli). You need to put your groups in the resources.

Answer (score 1):

This template is a subscription level template that creates a resource group. In this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.resources/2019-08-01/resourcegroups#quickstart-templates) you can find the ways to deploy this template.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the URI you seem to be targeting another resource group. You can't create a resource group within another resource group. You need to target the subscription instead!

Comment: how do I fix this ?

Comment: Like Gaurav asked above it depends on how you are deploying this template.

Comment: The intent is as a marketplace offer via the portal

Comment: I would edit your question to include the full pipeline Yaml or GUI context.